# Android: Cancel an Alarm Set From Another Activity

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I will try to explain this as best as I can. Basically, I have Activity 1 that uses an ExternalClass to do various things. Activity 2 also references Activity 1's object of said ExternalClass. From both of these activities I can set alarms using the AlarmManager, but I want to be able to cancel all the alarms created from either activity, from Activity 1.

All alarms are set using the same intent and the same AlarmManger (both created in the ExternalClass), but when I click my button in Activity 1 that is supposed to call myAlarms.cancel(intent) it only cancels the alarms that were created using the Activity 1 class.

The ExternalClass is referenced in Activity 2 by referencing the object of that class that was created in Activity 1 so they should both be using the same instance of the ExternalClass. I'm pretty sure it isn't canceling the alarms because of the context that was used when setting the alarms, but I can't figure out how to get around that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this issue I used to following code:

```
timerAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(myContext, i, alarmIntent, 0);
ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
intentArray.add(timerAlarmIntent);
myAM.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, timerAlarmIntent);
```

I set the requestCode to a unique id. This is within a for loop and i represents 0, 1, 2...

To cancel the alarms I had to add each alarm to a list and loop through the list when I wanted to cancel all alarms.

```
private void cancelAlarms(){
if(intentArray.size()>0){
    for(int i=0; i<intentArray.size(); i++){
        myAM.cancel(intentArray.get(i));
    }
    intentArray.clear();
}
```

}

Comment: hi ryandlf how to cancell only one alarm from list of alarm manager?thanx in advance

Answer (score 3):

To cancel and alarm you need to pass an equivalent `PendingIntent` (meaning `p1.equals(p2)` returns `true`) to the one used to create it. It doesn't matter from where you created the AlarmManager reference. How are you initializing the `PendingIntent` in both cases?

Two `PendingIntents` are considered equal if they both represent the same operation from the
 same package. Basically if you initialize two PendingIntents with equivalent Intents, they would be considered equal. EDIT: the documentation is obviously wrong about this, the requestCode is also used when comparing PendingIntents. See comments and other answer.

Comment: By "same" he means one that "equals". It doesn't have to be the same reference just one with the same properties.

Comment: You're right, thanks! My problem was I was setting the request code uniquely.

Comment: I had to retract my accepted answer because I realized that when I set the requestCode of the PendingIntent to a unique number the alarm works but does not cancel all of my alarms. When I set it with a static number such as 0, it only sets the first alarm.

Comment: That's funny because the requestCode is documented as unused, and as far as I can see the AlaramManager doesn't use it to match PendingIntents. What Android version is this on?

Comment: I guess it does use the RequestCodes to match PendingIntents. I came across a few different resources talking about the issue. I ended up having to set the codes uniquely and then add them to a list, then loop through the list when I wanted to cancel.

Comment: You are right. I wasn't reading all relevant code. `PendingIntent` comparison is defined in PendingIntentRecord.java and it does use the request code. The documentation is obviously wrong and there are at least two bugs filed for this: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=863 and http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7780